# Django form is being validated before it is submitted

Tags: python, django, forms, bootstrap-4

I have a custom bootstrap form which is displayed in the Dashboard. The problem is, that when the user goes to the dashboard, he sees validation errors right away, even though he did not submit the form yet (the text field should be required).

I do not understand why this is happening, any help is appreciated! :)
Picture of the problem (I do not want the red "The field is required" message to display now, only after submitting):

[image]

Form:

```
class MinitaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Minitask
        fields = ()


    def __init__(
        self,
        data=None,
        files=None,
        auto_id="id_%s",
        prefix=None,
        initial=None,
        error_class=ErrorList,
        label_suffix=None,
        empty_permitted=False,
        instance=None,
        use_required_attribute=None,
        minitask=None,
    ):
        super().__init__(
            data,
            files,
            auto_id,
            prefix,
            initial,
            error_class,
            label_suffix,
            empty_permitted,
            instance,
            use_required_attribute,
        )

        assert minitask is not None

        self.fields["selected_choice"] = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.RadioSelect(
                choices=[(val, val) for val in minitask.choices]
            ),
            required=False,
            label="Which of these emotions best describes your day?",
        )

        self.fields["reason"] = forms.CharField(label="Why?")
```

Views:

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def dashboard(request):
    task = request.user.current_weekly_task()
    user_id = request.user.id
    solutions = Solution.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
    minitask = request.user.current_minitask()
    minitasks = request.user.minitask_set.filter(selected_choice__isnull=False)

    if request.method == "POST":

        if "minitask" in request.POST:
            form = MinitaskForm(request.POST, minitask=minitask)
            if "selected_choice" not in request.POST:
                form.add_error("selected_choice", "Can't be blank")
                messages.error(request, "You must pick your today's emotion")
            if form.is_valid():
                minitask.reason = request.POST["reason"]
                minitask.selected_choice = request.POST["selected_choice"]
                minitask.user = request.user
                minitask.save()
                messages.success(request, "Your daily status has been updated.")

        return redirect("dashboard")
    else:
        mini_form = MinitaskForm(
            minitask=minitask,
            data={
                "reason": minitask.reason,
                "selected_choice": minitask.selected_choice,
            },
        )

    return render(
        request,
        "app/dashboard.html",
        {
            "solutions": solutions,
            "task": task,
            "mini_form": mini_form,
            "minitask": minitask,
            "minitasks": minitasks,
            "user": request.user,
        },
    )
```

Template:

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% bootstrap_form mini_form %}
  <button 
    type="Submit" 
    id="minitask-button" 
    class="save btn btn-pink" 
    name="minitask"
  >Save minitask</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your views:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    ...
else:
    mini_form = MinitaskForm(
        minitask=minitask,
        data={
            "reason": minitask.reason,
            "selected_choice": minitask.selected_choice,
        },
    )
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms):

> A Form instance is either bound to a set of data, or unbound.

Most of the times, a form gets its data from the user through a [POST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) request. (bound form)

The [GET](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) request provides the user with the form in order to fill it with data. (unbound form)

Therefore, through a GET request, you need to provide the user with an unbound form.

In your code, you declare that if the request is not POST (a GET request is not POST), then return a bound form populated with data you programmatically provide.

This does not make sense.

Chances are that if you insert a [`breakpoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint) after `else`, render the page with `./manage.py runserver` and type in the prompt provided in the console:

`minitask.reason == None` the result will be `True`.

The above, mean that you bound your form with data that contain an empty reason which is not allowed.

If you want to provide initial data in your [unbound form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#attributes-of-boundfield), you can do it using [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial):

```
mini_form = MinitaskForm(
    minitask=minitask,
    initial={
        "reason": minitask.reason,
        "selected_choice": minitask.selected_choice,
    },
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you explained it very well so that I understand that now :) Thanks!

Comment: @Zuzana I am glad I helped. You can also give [`Black`](https://github.com/psf/black) a try: `black ./*`.